# How can you make the fonts in Google Translate stay the same size?

Tags: google-translate

The fonts in the text areas in Google Fonts change size are you add more into the into area. I hate it. Can it be made to stay the size, with the default size, or a size of your choosing? [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/)

This is for Instant Translate turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        fontsize
// @namespace   SuperdoggyScripts
// @include     https://translate.google.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById('source').style.setProperty('font-size', '24px', 'important');
document.getElementById('result_box').style.setProperty('font-size', '24px', 'important');
```

Install a script manager (like Greasemonkey) and add this as a userscript.

You could also do this with a style manager such as Stylish.